# how to create get result and update form in custome table for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
<div class="row">
        <?php
        global $wpdb;   
        $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, phone, voucher FROM wp_offer_user", ARRAY_A);
        foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
            $rowid=$row[id];
            if($row[voucher] == null) { print_r ($row[id]); ?>          
                <div class="col-sm-12 tabel_voucher clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-2 voucher_box clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data_head">
                    <span class="voucher_head">First Name</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data">
                    <?php echo $row[firstname] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data_head">
                    <span class="voucher_head">Last Name</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data">
                    <?php echo $row[lastname] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data_head">
                    <span class="voucher_head">Mail ID</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data">
                    <?php echo $row[email] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data_head">
                    <span class="voucher_head">Mobile No</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data">
                    <?php echo $row[phone] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data_head">
                    <span class="voucher_head">Register Date</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data">
                    10/01/1991
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data_head">
                    <span class="voucher_head">Voucher</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-6 voucher_data">               
                    <form id="form-voucher">
                        <div class="field-wrap">                        
                            <input type="text" name="voucher" class="offer-voucher" />
                        </div> 
                        <button name="submit" class="offer-submit">Submit</button>
                        <div class="ajax-loader"></div>
                        <div class="login-error"></div>
                    </form>         
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php           
            }   
         }
        ?>
    </div>
```

This my function.php.
//User Profile Update

```
function user_voucher_form() {    
    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {        
        $voucher = $_REQUEST['voucher']; 
        $id = $_REQUEST['id']; 
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->update( 
            'wp_offer_user', 
            array( 
            'voucher' => $voucher   // string           
            ), 
            array( 'id' => $id ), 
            array( 
            '%s'    // value1           
            ), 
            array( '%d' ) 
            );
        if ( is_wp_error( $id ) ) {
            echo "Error";
        }
        die();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_user_voucher_form', 'user_voucher_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_user_voucher_form', 'user_voucher_form' );
```

I have update user profile form create. but value not store in db...which problem.....i have using WordPress wpdb.
How to create get result and update table...please help me

Comment: Take a look at the [$wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your get_results query doesn't look correct. What's in $rows when you do `var_dump($rows);`?

Try formatting this way [(see more query structures here)](http://wpdb.webstuffdepot.com/#Select_Get_data_out_of_the_database_):

```
$variable = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare('
        SELECT `column3`
        FROM `wp_table`
        WHERE `column1` = %s
        AND `column2` = %d
        ',
        $var1,
        123
    ),
    OBJECT
);
```

Also, your update structure looks correct - but please confirm that the `$voucher` is indeed the data to update and `$id` is the where statement:

```
$wpdb->update(
    wp_table,
        array(
            'column3' => $variable, // the column to update
        ),
        array(
            'column1' => 123, // the first WHERE argument
            'column2' => 'value2', // additional WHERE argument!
        ),
        array('%s'), // the format of the update value
        array(
            '%d', // the format of the first WHERE argument
            '%s' // the format of the second WHERE argument
        )
    );
```